# newline on a label vb.net within a for next loop

Tags: vb.net

how would i get a newline between each random 8 digit ID that I created, on the one label?

```
Public Class Form1
    'Write a program to display 1000 8-character random user IDs in a text 
    'box after you click a button.  Make sure the program verifies that none Of the IDs are identical. 
    'Each userid should include a mixture Of alphabetic characters And numbers.

Private Sub btnGenerateRandomID_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGenerateRandomID.Click
    Dim strChar As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
    Dim rand As New Random
    Dim strID As String
    Dim IdCheck As New List(Of String) With {.Capacity = 1000}

    For count_ids As Integer = 0 To 999
        For count_chars As Integer = 0 To 7
            strID += strChar(rand.Next(0, 62))
        Next

        If Not IdCheck.Contains(strID) Then
            IdCheck.Add(strID)
        End If
    Next

    lblRandomId.Text = strID
```

Comment: Make sure the `MultiLine` property is set to `True`

Comment: One of the requirements is: "Each userid should include a mixture Of alphabetic characters And numbers."  Does that mean it MUST have BOTH an alpha and a numeric character?...or could it be all letters or all numbers?

Comment: that lead me to the fact that I used a label (no multi line property) instead of a text box, and I set it to true. thanks.  Where in the code would I put either vbnewline or control.char.newline or vbcr?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things...

You need to reset `strID` between each generated ID, otherwise it will just become longer, and longer, and longer, and...you get the idea.

Instead of hard-coding a random number between 0 and 62, use the `.Length` property of `strChar`.  This way if you change the characters available in that string, your code will not need to be changed with respect to the random character being picked.

Speaking of Random, you should declare that as `static` so that it only gets instantiated once and gets re-used with each call.  Otherwise, if you click really fast you can actually end up with the same results since creating an instance of Random with no parameter uses the system clock as the seed.

If your ID was not unique, then it won't be added.  In that case, you'd end up with fewer than 1000 IDs.  You have to keep looping around until you find one that isn't in the list.

Lastly, I'd just use `String.Join()` with `Environment.NewLine` to add all of the IDs to the Label.

Here's what those changes might look like:

```
Dim strChar As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
Static rand As New Random
Dim strID As String
Dim IdCheck As New List(Of String) With {.Capacity = 1000} 'copyright stackoverflow inquiry

For count_ids As Integer = 0 To 999
    Do
        strID = ""
        For count_chars As Integer = 0 To 7
            strID += strChar(rand.Next(strChar.Length))
        Next
    Loop While IdCheck.Contains(strID)
    IdCheck.Add(strID)
Next

lblRandomId.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, IdCheck)
```

Comment: If you add a Panel to your Form and set AutoScroll to True, you can pop your Label in there and it will scroll for you.